# Camera2 taking multiple images in one capture session

Tags: android

Is it possible to take multiple images in one 'cameraDevice.createCaptureSession' with different focus distances, I'm trying to do some manual autofocus.

I know that I can just use multiple capture sessions and wait for the focus move before capturing the picture but can it be done in a single capture session?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *definitely* want to use a single `CameraCaptureSession` to issue multiple capture requests. Capture Sessions are not created lightly, you should only really be creating a new one when the set of possible output `Surface`s has changed.

The framework is designed to get access to a `CameraDevice` and to open up a single `CameraCaptureSession`, which is your actual interface to controlling the camera. You tell the Session to initiate captures using `.capture()`, `.captureBurst()`,`.setRepeatingRequest()`, and `.setRepeatingBurst()` by passing each one appropriately designed `CaptureRequest`s.

Each of the `CaptureRequest`s you issue to the `CameraCaptureSession` can have whatever set of camera control parameters you want (as long as your device supports them), such as the different focal distances you desire. When issued through the Session, they enter a pipeline and the results should essentially emerge in the same order as you request.

Comment: Perfect thanks much as I didn't really have any idea of the camera2 pipeline

Comment: Can some one share code, as camera2 have complicated code.